# unordered_map of boost::noncopyable can't return references from operator[]

Tags: c++, boost

To demonstrate my problem, consider this simple program that does not compile:

```
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <unordered_map>

class foo : boost::noncopyable { };

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, foo> m;
    auto & element = m[0];

    return 0;
}
```

Using the current version of boost (1.52), Visual Studio 2012 returns the error:
`cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable`.

The operator [] for std::unordered_map returns a reference to the element at the provided key, which at first glance seems like it should work -- I've asked for a reference to the element, not a copy of it.

My understanding of the problem is this (which might be wrong, as I haven't used C++ in a while). If the key is not found, unordered_map creates a new element and returns a reference to the new element. boost::noncopyable defines a (private) copy constructor but not a move constructor, and so a move constructor is not generated by the compiler. In its operator[], std::unordered_map makes use of std::move, but since boost::noncopyable doesn't define a move constructor, it falls back to the copy constructor. Since the copy constructor is private, the compilation fails.

What prompted this post is that I'm trying to create an unordered_map of boost::signal2::signal, which inherits from boost::noncopyable. Short of hacking the boost library, is there a simple workaround I can do? Wrapping the signal in a unique_ptr is an option, but it seems to me I might be doing something wrong here.

### Update:

I may have posted too soon! It appears impossible to add a subclass of boost::noncopyable to unordered_map. Insert, operator[], and emplace all use either a copy constructor (which is private), or a move operation (which doesn't exist for boost::noncopyable). To me this seems a major limitation. Is it even possible to create an unordered_map that contains boost::noncopyable objects? I'm explicitly *not* trying to copy them -- I want them to spend their entire lifespan inside the unordered_map.

Comment: In the process of moving items into in the hash table, copying is intrinsic to the nature of the operation you're requesting. You'll have the exact same problem doing an `insert()` as well. I was not aware one could even *have* a `map<>` or `unordered_map<>` with non-copyable entities (keys either for `map<>`, for that matter). If this is not the case, I'd kind of like to know myself. Would `emplace()` work for what you want?

Comment: You are right. It appears impossible to even add items to an unordered_map when they inherit from boost::noncopyable.

Comment: Check out the `emplace()` family. It may do what you're looking for. Good luck.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I think this may be a library bug. The standard says that `operator[]` only requires the mapped type to be default constructible, not copy or move constructible. You could have a map where you just default construct all the elements with `operator[]` and only modify them later.

Comment: @WhozCraig Sadly no :(. Emplace() has no move constructor to operate on, even though conceptually it's exactly what I want to do. I don't want to copy these objects. I just want them to live inside an unordered_map, but it seems impossible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not impossible to use a subclass of `boost::noncopyable` in an `unordered_map`, you simply have to define a move constructor for you type. C++ does not create a default move constructor if you've made your own copy construct (which is what `boost::noncopyable` does). Also, if it did define  default move constructor, it would try to call the parent's copy constructor which is private. So you must define a move constructor that doesn't try to call `boost::noncopyable`'s copy constructor. For example this works fine:

```
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <unordered_map>

struct foo : public boost::noncopyable
{
    foo() = default;
    foo(foo&&) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, foo> m;
    auto & element = m[0];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'll mark this as the solution, since it solves the general discussion. It still doesn't let me make an unordered_map of boost::signals2::signal though, since that object does not define a move constructor :(. It seems to be an oversight in the library design of signals (or it requires an update for C++11).

Answer (score 1):

This likely isn't exactly what you're looking for, but I figured I'd toss it out there. The one thing to note is the `second` value of the returned pair from `emplace()`, which indicates the second call does *not* introduce a new member, nor copy over the exiting member.

Again, I don't know if this is closer to what you want, but worth a shot. I likely did something wrong, as I'm not overtly familiar with the C++11 standard library as others. Sorry about that if so.

Finally, please note this is *not* attempting to address the OP's request of using `operator []()` for insert+access. Rather, it attempts to simply get a `boost::noncopyable` derivation constructed into an `unordered_map<>`. To access you would likely need a combination of the below as well as an initial `find()` to determine if the tag exists initially.

Anyway...

```
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

class Foo : public boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    Foo(int value) : value(value) {};

    void setValue(int value) { this->value = value; }
    int getValue() const { return value; }

private:
    int value;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, Foo> MyMap;
    MyMap mymap;

    // throw ("test".1) into the map
    auto p = mymap.emplace("test", 1);
    auto q = mymap.emplace("test", 2); // should not overwrite the first.

    // dump content
    cout << p.first->second.getValue() << '(' << p.second << ')' << ' '
         << q.first->second.getValue() << '(' << q.second << ')' << endl;

    // modify through the second returned iterator/bool pair.
    q.first->second.setValue(3);

    // dump again, see if p was also updated.
    cout << p.first->second.getValue() << '(' << p.second << ')' << ' '
         << q.first->second.getValue() << '(' << q.second << ')' << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
1(1) 1(0)
3(1) 3(0)
```